# how to solve SOAP services issue with portable class library?

Tags: soap, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

i have an issue using SOAP services from portable class library.

once i add the service refrence configuration file created empty  and calling any operation form Windows Phone or Windows store app project returns null value.

However if i added the refrence to WP or W8 project directly configuration file is  npot empty and operations return data

any reason for that ?

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as in full .NET. If you call a web service, the configuration file is searched for in the calling assembly, that is in your case the WP8 project.

You have two options. One is to copy the relevant configuration from app.config in the PCL to the WP8 porject or to create the web service configuration completely in code in your PCL so no config file anywhere is needed.

Comment: in App Config of PCL there is no configuration created for the service , so how can i implement the second option ?

Comment: What if you add the service reference to dummy Windows 8 app project to see what kind of config you need, then copy paste that into your proper project?

Comment: @AhmedEmad Which part doesn't work? Adding service reference? Using the copied config?

Comment: i mean the final result still the same after doing all that null values still return